# Good CSS library for print and "report" style formatting

Tags: html, css, django, printing, web-publishing

What is a good CSS library that can be used for generating reports, in both preview and print form?

The key in the "reports" is that they would look more like a formal (and printable) document than an actual web page.

Features that would be good:

1. Support for pagination, both for web and print
2. Printing support
3. Anything that would save time with page formatting (e.g., Landscape vs Portrait, A4 vs Letter, etc)
4. PDF support